# Youtube video player for button action in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to play an youtubue video when a button click. I am using XCD video player class for that. When i click the player will load but within 3 seconds it hide from view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can an instance of MPMoviePlayerViewController class and initialize it with your Youtube video URL.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

for this you'll need MediaPlayer framework in your project. So add MediaPlayer framework and import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h file in your class.

Comment: XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"PgSGQCk-63E"];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];

Comment: The above lines are my button action . I already added those frameworks. Also am not using my default application player instead using XCD view controller player.